# Variable identity with Python __init__ function - can anyone explain?

Tags: list, identity, init

I have a query about class **init** functions in Python. I was messing about trying to create a text adventure game type environment, with each room having an "items" property, stored as a list. I tried the following:

class Room:

```
def __init__(self,items=[]):
    self.items=items
```

But what I find with this is that every room that does not have an item defined on initiation gets not only an empty list, but the *same* empty list. Now if I create a bunch of rooms and append an item to one of them, the item appears in every room.

Easy enough to fix (manually assign an empty list to every room) but I don't understand why this happens. I would imagine creating room a would create a.items as an empty list, and room b would create b.items. But can anyone explain why these would be identical? And is there a way to produce the above function with a default value that creates a different list each time?

Cheers,

Billy.

Answer (score 4):

You have to understand default parameters in python.
When you write items=[], you create a global variable [], that you assign to item when a proper parameter is not provided.
This means every time items take the default value, it will be assigned the same [] object.
(Remember, as in Java, variables are just references to objects. All items variables will be references to the same object).

Formal explanation :
http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

What you could do is :

```
def __init__(self, items=None):
    if items is None:
        items = []
    self.items = items
```

this way, the default value, None, is never changed. When that is spotted, a new list is created (a real new list this time, not a global one).